# Ajax call return always a null object

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I know there are a lot of similar posts about this topic but I'm still not able to solve my problem.

I'm trying to call an ActioResult method with a button from my controller through ajax.
The problem is I always get back a null object

I'm quiet sure the problem is that I'm not able to bind the ajax call with the controller in the "data: " field

The AJAX call:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".milkmilk").click(function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("GoatMilk", "User")',
            datatype: "html",
            data: { name: 'name' },
            success: function (data) {
                $(this).closest('[data-rel]').html(data);
                },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("error!");
                }
        });
    });
});
```

The controller:

```
    public ActionResult GoatMilk(string name)
    {
        var rep = new GoatRepository();
        var goat = rep.GetAnimal(name);

        if(goat != null)
        {
            var model = FarmFactory.CreateAnimalModel<GoatViewModel>(goat) as GoatViewModel;

            model.Milk = rep.MilkProduction(goat);

            _MyEchoFarmDB.Update(goat);

            var rek = new FarmRepository();
            var deposit = rek.GetDeposit(name);
            deposit.Milk = goat.Milk;
            db.Update(deposit);

            return Json(model.Milk, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
        }
        return View();
    }
```

The Html code

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tbody>
       <tr>
           <td>
               <button class="milkmilk" data-rel="item.Name">MILK</button>
          </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
}
```

The code never enters inside the if(goat != null), so I always get back an error (notice that without the Ajax call the method works just fine)

Thank you!

Comment: show the related html, you need to pass name parameter from ajax call

Comment: You meant to use `data: "{name: 'the value'}"` not `data: "{id: '_id'}"`

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I added the html

Comment: @Poldro  console.log(data) in your ajax success and does ajax returning data.

Comment: @RamAnugandula I was answering you, sorry but I was out. 
I edited in the controller: return Json(new{success = true, name = model.Name, milk = model.Milk}...
and in the js: data:{'name': name}
there are progress since now I get an empty string insted a null but I'm still not able to make it work

Comment: If you mean you get an empty string here `ActionResult GoatMilk(string name)` then you can try this as ajax url `@Url.Action("GoatMilk", "Home", new {name="name"})`

Comment: @Bosco now i get back the string "name", is may be possible the problem involves the foreach loop inside the razor view?

Comment: @Poldro, which data are you trying to pass? My first comment had `data: "{name: 'the value'}"` but now I see you have a foreach loop, that will give you alot of buttons. What exactly do you want to achieve with this foreach loop? Am not sure about `data-rel`, but consider using hidden fields

Comment: I have a table with many objects inside, when I press the button, correlated to a specific object, I want to execute the method invoked and update the result of it. I use data-rel for another javascript inside the same razor view and it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may not be the cleanest way to solve this, but seems to run smoothly

HTML:

```
<td>
    <button type="button" class="milk" data-rel="@item.Name">MILK</button>
    <p class="milkGoat">@item.Milk</p>
</td>
```

Controller:

```
public JsonResult GoatMilk(string name)
{
     return Json(model.Milk, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
}
```

Ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".milk").click(function () {
            var name = $(this).data('rel');       
            var me = $(this)

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("GoatMilk", "User")',
                datatype: "html",
                data: { name: name },
                success: function (milk) {
                    me.next(".milkGoat").html(milk);
                },
                error: function (milk) {
                    alert("error!");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

instead of ActionResult try JsonResult method to return

```
 public JsonResult GoatMilk()
 {
     return Json();
 }
```

Comment: ActionResult is an abstract class. JsonResult is subtype of ActionResult